# Another "/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found" problem

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I've a project for ARM target device which needs to be cross compiled with gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.12 toolchain with a Ubuntu Linux machine.

This project is using libc.so.6 library. All worked fine until I changed my machine in order to update it to latest ubuntu version: 15.04.0+18.04.20180216-0ubuntu1

After setting up my environment and compiling my project, I run it and return message is:

```
/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /usr/local/sbin/libpi-base.so.1)
```

Unfortunately I can't update my target machine to GLIBC_2.17, I need to compile it with the old one (that's why all the other similar posts can't help me). Moreover, I don't have ldd command installed in my target machine so, I can't really understand which GLIBC version target device is expecting. 
What I suppose for now, is that glibc version included in my toolchain is the right one I need to link.

For now I set up as environment variables CC, AR, AS, OBJCOPY. Have I to set also CROSS_COMPILE environment variable?
Thank you very much,

Comment: Maybe this can add some details to the discussion. I tried to avoid over definitions by placing on Eclipse environment variables CC, AR, AS, OBJCOPY definitions (with "replace native environment  checkbox selected)